# Django filter __in keep order and duplicates

Tags: django, filtering

Let's say I have a list

```
items = [1,2,5,1,2,1]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get all Example objects in a list and keep order and duplicates. Like following:

```
def get_all_keep_order_and_duplicates():
    return [Example.objects.get(pk=pk) for pk in items]
```

My question is that is there a way to do this more efficiently, having a single query instead of getting each item individually?

So far I have tried following which keeps the order but doesn't return duplicates:

```
def get_all_keep_order():
    return Example.objects.filter(pk__in=items).order_by(
        Case(*[When(pk=pk, then=count) for count, pk in enumerate(items)])
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you have to do it in a query, why not do it in python:

```
exdict = {e.pk: e for e in Example.objects.all()}
return [exdict[e] for e in items]
```

This is just 1 database query.

Comment: I would prefer to do everything on database level, but seems to be overly complex or not sure if it's even possible. This is the best approach I've seen so far so probably end up implementing like this.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a natural database query to me. This is something that should be dealt with in Python.